# Parcel bundle web manifest inline

Tags: parceljs

Parcel can bundle CSS/style and EC6/Javascript inline with the generated HTML. How do I make Parcel do the same for the web manifest (manifest.json) of progressive web application?

[This is an example on how it should look like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49762630)